# Add item in parent window listbox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, window

Pretty much everything is said in question title. I have listbox of Animals in one window and button "Add new animal". When I click on that button new window appears, in which i will enter necessary date for animal and on the button "Save animal" i want to add that animal to listbox of first window.

```
<Window x:Class="HelloZooWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:HelloZoo.Model;assembly=HelloZoo.Model"
    xmlns:helloZooWpf="clr-namespace:HelloZooWPF"
    Title="Hello Zoo Wpf"
    Height="500"
    Width="525">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <model:Zoo Name="Belgrade Zoo">
        <model:Zoo.Animals>
            <model:Lion Name="Zeus" Weight="900" ImagePath="pack://application:,,,/Images/Lion.jpg"/>
            <model:Lion Name="Simba" Weight="200" ImagePath="pack://application:,,,/Images/Lion.jpg"/>
            <model:Antelope Name="Daisy" Weight="200" ImagePath="pack://application:,,,/Images/antelope.jpg"/>
            <model:Antelope Name="Rosie" Weight="200" ImagePath="pack://application:,,,/Images/antelope.jpg"/>
            <model:Antelope Name="Goldie" Weight="200" ImagePath="pack://application:,,,/Images/antelope.jpg"/>
        </model:Zoo.Animals>
    </model:Zoo>
  </Window.DataContext>
  <Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Animals}" Grid.Row="2" AlternationCount="2"/>
    <Button Content="New animal" Click="Button_Click"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Didn't copy all xaml code, like Grid.RowDefinitions and Grid.ColumnDefinitions. On Button_Click I just say `NewAnimalWindow n = new NewAnimalWindow(); n.ShowDialog();`.

NewAnimalWindow just have two textboxes for name and weight, combobox for animal type and button "Save animal" on which I want to add animal to collection of animal in parent window.

Answer (score 0):

Most trivial for implementation case would be to define custom constructor in NewAnimalWindow and pass AnimalsList there:

```
public class NewAnimalWindow : ...
{
    private List<Animal> _animals;
    public NewAnimalWindow(List<Animal> animals)
    {
        _animals = animals;
    }

    ....

    public SaveButton_Click(...)
    {
        Animal animal = new Animal(name, weight);
       _animals.Add(animal);
    }
}
```

Other options include:

1. Using global Animals list somewhere in the application
2. Sending some postback interface instead of animals list with method like AddAnimal(animal) which will be called upon save button click
3. Creating an event in NewAnimalWindow which will fire upon Save Button Click.
4. Many others, probably.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a Property on the NewAnimalWindow which allows acces to the created object.

**MainWindow**

```
var animalWindow = new NewAnimalWindow();
animalWindow.ShowDialog();

if (animalWindow.DialogResult.HasValue && animalWindow.DialogResult.Value)
{
    var createdAnimal = animalWindow.CreatedAnimal;
    Animals.Add(createdAnimal);
}
```

**NewAnimalWindow**

```
  <Button IsDefault="True" Click="Button_OK_Click">Close</Button>
  <Button IsCancel="True">Cancel</Button>

private Animal _animal;

public Animal CreatedAnimal
{
  get
  {
    return _animal;
  }
}

private void Button_OK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  DialogResult = true;
}
```

Alternatively if you are working with ViewModels you can use the Mediator pattern and fire events when an animal is created, so the main view model can add it to the list..